# Module overwriting a view

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-view, social

Is it possible to overwrite `sharing.phtml` view by external module?

My point is to add a new social button. I want to publish a module in marketplace, so I don't want to modify any local file. I read about adding files to `/app/design/frontend` and configuring file overwrite in XML config. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,you can do by creating new module.

- Step1: `Need define layout for module at config.xml file`.

`<frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
        <!-- insert a layout file in current layout --> 
                <sharefile><!-- identifier for layout file -->
                    <file>sharefile.xml</file> <!-- layout file name -->
                </sharefile>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>`

- Step2: `On this layout file need to change template of share block using setTemplate function`

`<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="BlockNameInXml">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>YourtemplatefileLocation/Yourphtml.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>`

If you using `rwd package` then you can try add below code your custom  xml layout `sharefile.xml` .

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.sharing"> 
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>YourtemplatefileLocation/Yourphtml.phtml</template>
        </action> 
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

### Full module Approach:

**1.  Define Config file :** First of all create module control file Module name as 
    **Amit_Sharefile.xml** at **app/etc/modules/**

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Sharefile>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
         <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Amit_Sharefile>
    </modules>
</config>`

**2. Define Main Configuration file:** Create a config.xml ,where we are declared
    table,model,blocks,layouts file , controllers,In a word  we can say 
    this configuration file of this  extension.

Path Of `config.xml` is `app/code/community/Amit/Sharefile/etc/`

As we define `codepool` is `community` that it path `app/code/community`

Here `Amit` folder  is `Namespace` of module and  `Sharefile` is `module name`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Sharefile>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Sharefile>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <sharefile>
                    <file>sharefile.xml</file>
                </sharefile>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**3.  Create layout file :** `sharefile.xml` should be  path
    `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/layout/` and code is

`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view> 
    <reference name="product.info.sharing"> <!-- block name in layout of share file -->
        <action method="setTemplate"> <!-- Change the phtml using setTemplate function -->
            <template>YourtemplatefileLocation/Yourphtml.phtml</template>
        </action> 
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

`

Comment: Thanks for great answear! It will work only for default rwd template? Am I right @AmitBera ? Can I create something more universal?